# flutter: pass parameter between stateful widget perform calculation before displaying

Tags: flutter

I have a code snippet that looks like this:

```
class RecordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int recordObject;

  RecordPage({Key key, @required this.recordObject}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordPageState createState() => new _RecordPageState(recordObject);
}

class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {
  int recordObject
 _RecordPageState(this. recordObject);  //constructor
   // int result=100 * recordObject;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {.    //closure has access
   //.....
  }
}
```

My problem is that I dont want to just display recordObject. i want to use it for some process like :

```
int result=100 * recordObject;
```

then i will display result not recordObject,
the error i get is:

```
Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. _RecordPageState(this. recordObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass parameters to `State` class using it's constructor.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
class RecordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int recordObject;

  RecordPage({Key key, @required this.recordObject}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordPageState createState() => new _RecordPageState(recordObject);
}

class _RecordPageState extends State<RecordPage> {

 int result;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // use the value of recordObject 
    result = 100 * widget.recordObject;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {.    //closure has access
   //.....
  }
}
```

Use the value of `result` in your widget tree like:

```
Text('$result'),
```

Comment: You can accept the accept if it answered your question @OnaloJoseph

Comment: I tried but i couldn't because of my reputation point... how can i increase my reputation? @void